# TDD workflow in Xcode - how to "quick fix" when doing red-green-refactor?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, tdd, redgreen

One of the things which makes TDD nice is the ability to generate code after you have written a test. This is done with the *Quick Fix* option in Eclipse (Cmd-F1) - or with similar option using Alt-Enter in Jetbrains tools. Most of the usage just involves four options:

- Create new class
- Create new method
- Create new property
- Create new instance variable

Is there any way to add this ability to Xcode using a plugin, Automator or anything else? I feel that with just four of these in place I could return to using Xcode instead of being stuck in Appcode.

Comment: Still looking for an answer to this ....

Comment: Filed a rdar issue: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=3093402

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think this is possible. Xcode's refactoring tools aren't as powerful as some other IDE's (though it has been improved recently). And expanding Xcode with plugins or scripting is even more difficult since the update to 4.0 (before that at least scripting was possible). Now not even Apple Script support is as complete as is should be.

Comment: I'm aware that this is not going to be easy - but surely somebody must have tried to do something about this?

Answer (score 0):

I've come across the same need but unfortunately the **current** Xcode versions do not have much support for code refactoring. One tool I stumbled upon is [Accessorizer](http://www.kevincallahan.org/software/accessorizer.html)

I have not tried it but the features and the recommendations look promising.

Hope that helps :)